# Generate array of N sample from a list of N means and N sigmas

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a numpy array of size N which contains [x,y] pixel locations. I want to slightly move every pixel in both x and y directions. What I want to achieve is to use every x value as the mean and randomly select new value around it from a normal distribution with configurable sigma. Same will be done for new y values

My problem is that I have to loop for every pixel and tediously use the following:

```
for i in range(len(pixels)):
    pixel = pixels[i]
    x = pixel[0]
    y = pixel[1]
    new_x = numpy.random.normal(x, std_deviation_x)
    new_y = numpy.random.normal(y, std_deviation_y)
    pixel[i][0] = new_x
    pixel[i][1] = new_y
```

I wonder if there is a way or any random function implementation which accept list of means, and list of sigmas to return list of N samples where each sample is of corresponding mean and sigma in the list

Comment: Have you tried passing a list of means and sigmas to np.random.normal? It accepts arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scipy.stats.norm` accepts vector parameters:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> 
# mean = 0, 1, -1  -  std = 1, 2, 2
# we draw 10,000 samples per parameter set to validate the mean ...
>>> stats.norm([0, 1, -1], [1, 2, 2]).rvs((10000, 3)).mean(axis=0)
array([ 0.02597611,  1.01131576, -0.9446429 ])
# ... and the std
>>> stats.norm([0, 1, -1], [1, 2, 2]).rvs((10000, 3)).std(axis=0)
array([ 0.99299587,  2.0055516 ,  1.99656472])
# if you need just one sample per parameter set:
>>> stats.norm([0, 1, -1], [1, 2, 2]).rvs()
array([-1.23528454,  3.77990026, -3.49572846])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just sample from a normal distribution with mean 0 and then move the value to the new mean.

Cleaning and improving your code slightly, it should look like this.

```
# We create all new (x,y) in one go
rand_x = numpy.random.normal(0, std_deviation_x, len(pixels))
rand_y = numpy.random.normal(0, std_deviation_y, len(pixels))

for i in range(len(pixels)):
    x, y = pixels[i]  # using unpacking

    # now we shift the mean
    new_x = x + rand_x[i]
    new_y = y + rand_y[i]

    # reasignment
    pixels[i][0] = new_x
    pixels[i][1] = new_y
```

For sure this can further improved and made more optimal, there are still quite some superfluous assignments.